# When accessing SQL DB from android device, my httpEntity is returning null, can anyone inform me as to why this is?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

This my connector class that should call on the php script to access the database. When debugging I find that httpEntity is returning null therefore not detecting any results from the database. The url works fine in the browser so im not sure whether or not this is the issue.

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ApiConnector {


public JSONArray GetAllCustomers()
{
    // URL for getting all customers
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    String url = "mydburl";

    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

    try
    {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        Log.v("response code", httpResponse.getStatusLine()
                .getStatusCode() + "");
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();

        //Log Errors Here



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jsonArray;


}

}
```

php Script (works in browser)

```
<?php


$con = $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

// Check connection
if (!$con)
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
  }
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `locations` ';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $output[]=$row;
  }

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: your android browser or pc browser?

Comment: Are you running this on the main thread?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: on my PC browser, and yes this was just a tutorial run on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

There was in fact two problems here, the first was to do with my php script, once i modified it to run mysqli instead of my sql it ran correctly.

Another was to do with the ip address i was passing through, the device was trying to read from the localhost from my device rather than the localhost of my laptop. To fix this i entered my ipv4 address.